# Problems with Sanctum Laravel 8 for API Authenthication (won't delete token on logout)

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

We installed correctly Sanctum for api authenthication.
 After the login we distiguished two roles: one for admins and one for users with the help of laratrus. 
 We created also a new Controller that handles all authentication parts(registration, login ,logout).
 After the login we distiguished two roles: one for admins and one for users with the help of laratrust library. 
The problem is that when we try to do the login using postman it gives us this error:

[image]

Even though the application insert correctly the token row in the database.
The second problem is when we tried to login with browser, it gives us no error and the redirections are correct, but when we tried to logout the token still is present in the db.

This is our AuthController.php:

```
protected function register(Request $request){
    
    
}

protected function login(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json([
            'status_code' => '400',
            'message' => 'Bad request'
        ]);
    }

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)){

        return response()->json([
            'status_code' => '500',
            'message' => 'Non autorizzato'
        ]);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;

    if($user->hasRole('administrator')){
        
        return redirect()
            ->route('admin')
            ->with([
                'status_code' => '200',
                'token' => $token
            ]);
    }
    if($user->hasRole('user')){
        
        return redirect()
            ->route('cliente')
            ->with([
                'status_code' => '200',
                'token' => $token
            ]);
    }

}

protected function logout(Request $request){

    $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

    return redirect()
            ->route('welcome')
            ->with([
                'status_code' => '200',
                'message' => 'token cancellato correttamete'
            ]);
}
```

This is our api.php:

```
Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('api.login');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {

//Operazioni di gestione e creazione corso scii per maestri
Route::post('/tipo', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'createtipo']);
Route::post('/corso', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'createcorso']);
Route::get('/mostracorsi', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'mostracorsi']);
Route::get('/mostracorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'mostracorso']);
Route::put('/updatecorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'updatecorso']);
Route::delete('/deletecorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'deletecorso']);

//Operazioni di gestione prenotazioni ed iscrizioni per clienti impianto scii
Route::post('/iscrizione', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'iscrizione']);
Route::get('/vedicorso/{idCorso}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'vedicorso']);
Route::delete('/deleteiscrizione/{idUtente}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class, 'deleteiscrizione']);

//Route per il logout
Route::post('/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('api.logout');
});
```

Also, how can we attach the API system authentication with Laravel Template blades?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem maybe, you didn't save the token on your front end, It looks like you make successfully login but you didn't  save the token. Sanctum middleware will only allow the request after it identifies the header from fronted I am not sure what is in your fronted but I believe all SPA work the same, I am sure the problem is in fronted not in back-end.  with reference to my vue js SPA. I save the token when log in and after that whenever I make request I access the token by  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`. You can see my example below is my dashboard after successfully login

```
  <script>
export default {
  components: { SideMenu, Profile, Sidebar, PersonalDetails },
  data(){
      return {
          drawer: true,
          currentUser: {},
          user: {},
          user_info: { profile: {} },
          token: localStorage.getItem('user_data')
      }
  },
 methods: {
      getUser(){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user').then(response => {
            this.currentUser = response.data
            this.user = this.currentUser.user
            if (this.user.roles= []) {
                this.$router.push({ name: 'Roles'})
            }
            axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile/' + this.user.id).then(response => {
                this.user_info = response.data
                console.log(response.data)
            })
        }).catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors)
        })
      },
  },
  created(){
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}` 
      this.getUser()  
      this.isCreated = true   
  }
}
</script>
```

I believe your logout function will work out after you resolve this.

Comment: We used jQuery on Laravel Blade template, does it work the same?

Comment: I don't think its a good idea as per laravel sactum docs, it for API  that means it is exchange of data from different url ie, but jQuery give request from the same website. I would advice you guys to use default laravel authentications methods. jQuery will have no problem with that since it the same site it shares default session